# IntelliJ Datanucleus Enhancer plugin not working

Tags: intellij-idea, datanucleus

The project I'm developing uses Datanucleus 2.0.3, so I'm using those libraries for enhancement (plugin is configured to use the module dependencies as well). IntelliJ version 12.0.1 on a Ubuntu 12.4 machine. I know the 2.0.3 is ancient history but upgrading it at least now is not an option for me.

From gradle all works fine. I imported by project to IntelliJ and when I ran the tests from junit I got the usual ClassNotPersistenceCapableException so I recalled I need a plugin for this.

I installed the newest plugin (tried both the beta and the last stable version) and configured the plugin to enhance my this one module. I chose JDO and applied, it discovered all the classes annotated for persistence, I rebuilt the whole project, ran the tests again and the same error occurs.

some things I've noticed / checked:
- the Enchaner is ticked in "Build / Datanucleus Enhancer"
- looked for multiple datanucleus jars, but there is only one
- haven't seen any message in IntelliJ in the Event Log saying is has done enhancing (the gradle enhancer logs such a message)
- haven't seen any error messages in IntelliJ saying enhancement failed, I also didn't find any log files outside IntelliJ (should there be any?)
- when I manually added the gradle built classes at the top of the classpath for the test the tests passed - but this is no good
- the module has the following datanucleus 2.0.3 jars on it's classpath: datanucleus-core, datanucleus-enhancer, datanucleus-connectionpool, datanucleus-rdbms and the asm-3.1.jar (the dependencies say it's 3.0-4.0 so this one should fit)

I have no idea why it sees the classes but doesn't enhance them, or maybe it does try and silently fail ... but then I don't know how to diagnose the problem

No other ideas come to my mind, please advise what to check or what to try.

Comment: It may be not compatible with your IDEA version, please contact the plug-in vendor for help.

Comment: same situation with a different setting: mac os x 10.8.4, intellij 12.1.4 & datanucleus 3.0.3